# div height: 0; without any floating child elements?

Tags: html, css

Here's some HTML I have

```
<nav class="navlist">
    <span class="left">
        <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    </span>
    <span class="right">
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </span>
</nav>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.navlist {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}
.navlist span {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
.navlist .left {
    right: 0px;
    margin-right: 50%;
    padding-right: 75px;
}
.navlist .left li {
    margin-left: 75px;
}
.navlist .right {
    left: 0px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    padding-left: 75px;
}
.navlist .right li {
    margin-right: 75px;
}
.navlist li{
    display: inline;
}
.navlist li a {
    font-family: "Futura Thin", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Why is the height of the `<nav>` element 0 instead of wrapping the height around the child elements? I've tried absolutely everything, adding `overflow: auto;` etc. and nothing works without simply defining the height manually, which is definitely not what I want. Any help?

Comment: i guess you need to show what you really expect to have in the end. invalid code + mixed of absolute and float won't do anything nice :)

Comment: @GCyrillus Yes this isn't very good HTML at all, I was trying to create something in a silly way now I've taken a second glance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<span>` should be `<ul>` or `<li>` should be `<span> or any inline-elements` to make a valid code. best is to use `<ul><li><a>` for a list of links.

`position:absolute;`(or fixed) takes element out of the natural flow of the page, so `<nav>` have no content to make it grow.

Comment: Thank you so much, I completely didn't notice about the `<span>` either. Great answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You have taken `<li>` without `<ul> or <ol>` it is not a best practice.

absolute: The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element, So its container doesnt have specific value.

```
<ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
</ul>
```

Need to wrap as above and need to give style to remove its default bullets.

Answer (score 0):

this is caused by your

```
position:absolute
```

rule on the span elements.
Absolutely positioned elements don't fill the parent container, causing it to have a height of 0px.
Try making the same layout without using absolute positioning, and you should be fine.

Also, the `<li>` elements should be in a `<ul>` parent, not a `<span>`

Answer (score 0):

Your child elements are positioned as absolute, thus also taking them out of the flow. Because of this, the .navlist element doesn't know how to expand.

Use floats to position your navigation lists and then user the `overflow:hidden` fix on the .navlist to have it expand to fit the child elements.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, positioning a child element as absolute will pull it out of the layout, its parent will then always have a height of 0 as it technically has no layout inside of it.

It completely depends on what your end result should look like so its hard to advise but a little reduced case of what you may want ( with a red background colour to make it obvious height is set on the nav is here:

http://jsbin.com/osobor/1/

```
 .navlist {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    background: red;
}

.navlist ul {
    float: left;
    width:50%;
    padding:0; 
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.navlist .right {
    float:right;
}

.navlist li a {
    font-family: "Futura Thin", sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Edit: Also your spans should be UL ( or OL ) elements if you're nesting LI's within them ( I've added this to the jsbin example )